# spring binder giving error on jsr validation

Tags: regex, spring-mvc

I have property annotated as

```
@Size(min = 1, max = 50, groups = { EmployerRegistration.class })
@Pattern(regexp="[^,]" , groups = { EmployerRegistration.class })
private String companyName;
```

pattern i have added to make sure it should accept anything accept comma.

But it is failing for all cases.

```
SNo | Test Date |  Test Result
1.  | Zuned,A   |  Fails 
2.  | Zuned A   |  Fails
```

I am unable to figure out why it is failing for second case. Can anybody help me out what i am missing?

I think issue is in regular expression -> how to write regular expression that allow any word accept comma.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The regex was incorrect. I used below regex it worked.

```
^[^,]*[^,]*$
```